# MICROSOFT.OFFICE.INTEROP.WORD - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, microsoft-word

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou precisando de ajuda com esse problema utilizando o Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Detalhe: executando a aplicação no visual studio ela funciona normalmente, sem nenhum erro, porém, se jogo no IIS, ele aparece esse erro. Antes dele, tinha problema com permissão COM, alterei as permissões e agora aparece esse erro. Olhem as fotos que mostram tudo que já fiz até aqui. Segue algumas informações do que já foi feito.

1 - Adicionei as permissões do IIS_IUSRS e SERVIÇOS DE REDES em Permissão de acesso do COM específico (no caso Documento do Microsoft Word 97 - 2003);

2 - A identidade do COM está definido como usuário interativo;

3 - Existe a referencia do Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word no projeto;

4 - O Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word existe no computador, ou seja, o Office está instalado (versão de 64bits). O sistema operacional é 64bits também.

Preciso muito resolver esse problema, pois o projeto foi desenvolvido - mais de 3 meses - em cima do Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, onde utilizo a conversão para PDF e também, uso um método pra modificar o arquivo antes de converte-lo para PDF.

**CÓDIGO**

Método p/ conversão para PDF

```
 public static void ConverterEmPdf(string entrada, string saida)
    {
        var missing = Type.Missing;
        var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(entrada);
        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(saida, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)wordDocument).Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```

Método para alteração de documento

```
public static void InserirNumero(object fileName, object saveAs, int numero)
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        if (!File.Exists((string) fileName)) return;
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = false;
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        var aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
            ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing);
        aDoc.Activate();
        LocalizarESubstituir(wordApp, "<numerodocumento>", numero);
        aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)aDoc).Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);  
    }
```

Método localizar e substituir usado no método anterior

```
private static void LocalizarESubstituir(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        var missing = Type.Missing;

        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        if (replaceWithText.ToString().Length < 250)
        {
            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase,ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                                          ref nmatchAllWordForms,ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,  ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
        }
        else
        {
            wordApp.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing,
        ref missing);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)wordApp).Application.Selection.Text = (string)replaceWithText;
        }
    }
```

**IMAGENS DE TUDO QUE JÁ FIZ PARA TENTAR RESOLVER O PROBLEMA**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional? É um *Windows Service*?

Comment: @qmechanik esse das imagens é o windows 7. Já tentei no Windows Server 2012 e também não funcionou, como não poderia ficar mexendo muito no servidor principal, optei por mexer num pc momentaneamente.

Comment: Experimente usar a ferramenta [FUSLOGVW.EXE - view .NET assembly binding issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para descobrir exatamente o que está ocorrendo.<br> Use as informações deste [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/47733) para configurar o uso da ferramenta.

Comment: Você está publicando com o Visual Studio?
É necessário enviar as bibliotecas para a pasta correspondente no site.<br>
No caso há uma pasta específica para a DLL. Mais detalhes acesse https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx